# Excel how to add cell content at the start of every other cells

Tags: excel, vba

I would like a cell to start at the beginning of everything else I write such as E1 begins on everything i wrote therefore I would like to get:

-Hello A
-Hello B ect. by just adding text with no formulas on the A column and still see "hello" written at the start

[image: I want to make "hello world" without the need to add (=E1&)]

Comment: If you don't want formula then why did you tag it formula? So you want VBA?

Comment: formula is necessary on E1 or else. what i meant is that I want to be able to write no formulas on the A column and still see "hello" written at the start

Comment: You write `Hello A` and `Hello B` in your text and in your example picture you have `Hello world!` it's slightly confusing. If you write "Hello" in E1, and then type "A" in E2, Do you want E2 to change to "Hello A"?

Comment: that is correct, I want to type "A" in E2 and "Hello A" should appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you paste this code in your sheet object in VBA editor then it will change the value in column E (except row 1) to become `=E1&" "&[Own value]`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Value <> "" And Target.Column = 5 And Target.Row > 1 And Cells(1, Target.Column).Value <> "" Then
        Target.Value = Cells(1, Target.Column).Value & " " & Target.Value
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

These three values was just A, B, C and the "Hello" was added automatically:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is what I wanted, May I ask how I could also change the code in VBA so hello appears at the end of my cell?

Comment: This line here is what dictates the order: `Target.Value = Cells(1, Target.Column).Value & " " & Target.Value`. if you change this to `Target.Value = Target.Value & " " & Cells(1, Target.Column).Value` then it will say `A Hello`

Comment: Thank you very much, your explanation is very insightful.